# Reading evtx file too big

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm processing an evtx file with a size more than 2GB.
In my C# program if I do something like this

```
EventLogReader reader = new EventLogReader("*[System/EventRecordID>0]");
for (EventRecord eventInstance = reader.ReadEvent(); eventInstance != null; eventInstance = reader.ReadEvent())
{
    ...
}
```

The for loop never run becasue eventInstance is equal to null.
I only have this problem with large evtx files.

the other way is to read evtx files using LINQ as described in this article
https://phejndorf.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/using-c-and-linq-to-read-a-windows-eventlog-file-evtx/

If I use this approach, I can read the file with out problem.

Is't a good approach?

Any comments?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I have been working on this an in first scenario, the problem is that the EventRecordID is too big. If I set the query to "*". It works fine. I don't understand this because RecordID type in EventRecord is long.

The second scenario works always fine.

Answer (score 0):

The approach mentioned in your question is fine provided you want to write the code for loading the file etc.

Ideally, one should use [Microsoft's Log Parser](http://blog.codinghorror.com/microsoft-logparser/).  Using this one simply write SQL like queries to fetch the statistics.

Comment: Log Parser is from 2005. Ver. 2.2. Is this the last version?

Comment: Yes it is the latest version